# Ввод данных в таблицу

Tags: mysql, связи

Имеются 3 таблицы:

```
Vigruzka
User_Name0 Name0 DisplayName0 Publisher0 LastW
Anna.CM    Anna  Skype        Microsoft  2.0.9
...
rows 700

Users
Id_users User_Name0 Name0
1        Anna.CM    Anna
...
rows 3

Programs
Id_programs DisplayName0 Publisher0
1           Skype        Microsoft
...
rows 300
```

Первичные ключи заданы.

Необходимо создать таблицу Updates со связями, чтобы получилось вот так:

```
Updates
Id_updates id_Users Id_programs LastW
1          1        1           2.0.9
...
rows 300
```

Количество записей в таблицах разные (Без дубликатов) в Users 3, Programs 300, Vigruzka 700.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня нет сейчас возможности проверить запрос (возможны синтаксические ошибки), но вот, ИМХО, стартовая точка откуда Вы можете начать:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.Id_users as id_Users,Programs.Id_programs as Id_programs, Vigruzka.LastW as LastW
FROM 
    Programs, Vigruzka, Users
where 
     Programs.DisplayName0 = Vigruzka.DisplayName0
AND 
     Vigruzka.Name0 = Users.Name0
INSERT INTO Updates
```

При этом поле `Id_updates` следует сделать автоинкрементным. Естественно, все это предполагает уникальность `Programs.DisplayName0` и `Users.Name0`

Comment: Спасибо буду тестить

Comment: Получилось! немного изменил код, но все работает, Спасибо

Comment: Очень рад, что помог  :)